# error: package com.google.android.gms.drive does not exist

Tags: java, android, dependencies

Hi everyone I have this problem that I can't solve even tho I checked on StackOverflow and I tried all the solutions but nothing is working.

So bellow I will put the dependencies and sync them and everything seems ok but when I press compile I get this error:
package com.google.android.gms.drive does not exist

but I included the dependency and I can't understand why I get this error.

Can anyone help me, please? Thank you.

```
dependencies {


implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.1.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'


implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'



// Add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
// Add the SDKs for any other Firebase products you want to use in your app
// For example, to use Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'



implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
// FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would recommend you is to check if on top of the `build.gradle` you added the plugin

> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

then do a clean build, from Build -> Clean build

If should not work downgrade the dependencies just to be sure is not any particular bug from the current version of the play services. Let us know!